# row-wise calculation of cosine similarity in pandas without looping

Tags: pandas, performance, loops, trigonometry, similarity

I have a pandas dataframe df with many rows. For each row, I want to calculate  the cosinus similarity between the row's columns A (first vector) and the row's columns B (second vector). At the end, I aim to get a vector with one cosine similarity value  for each row. I have found a solution but it seems to me like it could be done much faster without this loop. May anyone give me some feedback on this code? 
Thank you very much!

```
for row in np.unique(df.index):
            cos_sim[row]=scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(df[df.index==row][columnsA], 
                                          df[df.index==row][columnsB])

df['cos_sim']=cos_sim
```

Here comes some sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'featureA1': [2, 4, 1, 4],

                   'featureA2': [2, 4, 1, 4],

                   'featureB1': [10, 2, 1, 8]},

                   'featureB2': [10, 2, 1, 8]},

                  index=['Pit', 'Mat', 'Tim', 'Sam'])

columnsA=['featureA1', 'featureA2']
columnsB=['featureB1', 'featureB2']
```

This is my desired output (cosine similarity for Pit, Mat, Tim and Sam):

```
cos_sim=[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I am already receiving this output with my method, but I am sure the code could be improved from a performance perspective

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a sample data and desired output :)

Comment: Thanks, @Chris, for this hint. I have added comes some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

several things you can improve on :)

1. Take a look at the `DataFrame.apply` function. pandas already offers you looping "under the hood".

```
df['cos_sim'] = df.apply(lambda _df: scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(_df[columnsA], _df[columnsB])
```

or something similar should be more performant

2. Also take a look at `DataFrame.loc`

```
df[df.index==row][columnsA]
```

and

```
df.loc[row,columnsA]
```

should be equivalent

3. If you really have to iterate over the dataframe (should be avoided again due to performance penalties and it is more difficult to read and understand), pandas gives you a generator for the rows (and id)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(row[columnsA], row[columnsB])
```

4. Finally as mentioned above to get better answers on stackoverflow, always provide a concrete example where the problem is reproducible. Otherwise it is much harder to interpret the question correctly and to test a solution.

Comment: Wow, @maow, thanks a lot!! This helped me so much both for the problem itself and my general coding skills! What a pleasant first stackoverflow experience :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old post but I am replying for future readers. I created https://github.com/ma7555/evalify for all those rowwise similarity/distance calculations (disclaimer: i am the owner of the package)